# Quarkus project REST API responses hang if quarkus-amazon-lambda-http dependency present

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, quarkus, resteasy

I have the following minimal Quarkus project example. Without the `quarkus-amazon-lambda-http` dependency, the project returns the correct response when the GET endpoint is called, and even a much larger one (10,000 items).

However when the `quarkus-amazon-lambda-http` dependency is added to `pom.xml` the size of the possible response is severely limited. The code will only run if the response size if very small (it works with 50 items, but not 100).

When I run the project locally, the response code 200 OK is returned, but no body, and it just hangs trying to retrieve body indefinitely (tried through Postman, browser, curl).

I have tried with both reactive and non-reactive dependencies for the pom.xml and there is the same result with both. I have tried to use other versions of Quarkus also, such as 3.6.0.

Resource:

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/cars")
public class ExampleResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Car> cars() {
        List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();

        //works if there are only 50 items in list
        //without lambda dependency, works if there 10000+
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            carList.add(new Car(Long.valueOf(i), "Car(" + i + ")", Double.valueOf(i) * 100, Double.valueOf(i) + 100,
                    Double.valueOf(i), new Date(), new Date()));
        }

        return carList;
    }
}
```

Model object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Car {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Double weight;
    private Double length;
    private Double width;
    private Date dateBuilt;
    private Date dateAdded;
}
```

pom.xml file dependencies and versions:

```
<properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.6.4</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</surefire-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I calculated the response body size and added the size to the Content-Length response header the request body would be retrieved.

```
@Provider
public class ContentLengthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
        
        private static final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.newBuilder().build();
    
        
        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
            
        }
    
        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
            
            if (responseContext.getEntity() != null && MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.equals(responseContext.getMediaType())) {
                var entity = jsonb.toJson(responseContext.getEntity());
                responseContext.setEntity(entity);
                responseContext.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, entity.getBytes().length);
            }
        }
```